# Django session passes argument from a view to another but sets the same value for all user instances

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am passing an (**is_followed**) parameter from one class based view **FollowToggleAPIView** to another **UserDetailAPIVIew**. I do this using Django session (from reading other thread on this platform) in the hope of displaying the follow-status (**True** or **False**) of the **user_to_toggle** variable on the **UserSingleProfileSerializer**.

Here are my views:

```
class UserDetailAPIVIew(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
'''
Displays a list of a user's posts
'''
serializer_class = UserSingleProfileSerializer
queryset = User.objects.all()

def get_object(self):
    self.object = get_object_or_404(User,                                
                    username__iexact=self.kwargs.get('username')
                    )
    return self.object

def get_serializer_context(self):
    '''
    passing the extra is_following argument to the UserDetailAPIVIew
    '''
    context = super(UserDetailAPIVIew, self).get_serializer_context()
    is_followed = self.request.session.get('followed')
    context.update({'followed': is_followed})
    return context


class FollowToggleAPIView(APIView):
'''
Uses the custom model manager for user toggle follow
'''
def get(self, request, username, format=None):
    user_to_toggle = get_object_or_404(User, username__iexact=username)
    me = request.user
    message = 'Not allowed'

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        is_followed = UserProfile.objects.toggle_follow(me, user_to_toggle)
        request.session['followed'] = is_followed
        return Response({'followed': is_followed})
    return Response({'message': message}, status=400)
```

The **toggle_follow** method is defined in the custom model manager as follows:

```
class UserProfileManager(models.Manager):

def toggle_follow(self, user, to_toggle_user):
    ''' follow unfollow users '''
    user_profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    if to_toggle_user in user_profile.following.all():
        user_profile.following.remove(to_toggle_user)
        added = False
    else:
        user_profile.following.add(to_toggle_user)
        added = True
    return added


class UserProfile(models.Model):
'''
Extends the Django User model
'''
user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                            related_name='profile')
following = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                    blank=True,
                                    related_name='followed_by')


objects = UserProfileManager()

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('profiles:detail',
                        kwargs={'username':self.user.username})

def __str__(self):
    return 'Username: {} [ Followers ({}); 
         Following({})]'.format(self.user.username,                                   
         self.user.followed_by.all().count(),
         self.following.all().count())
```

The urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/$', UserDetailAPIVIew.as_view(), 
        name='user-posts-api'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/follow/$', 
        FollowToggleAPIView.as_view(), name='follow-api'),
]
```

The only problem is that the value of (**is_followed**) displayed in **UserSingleProfileSerializer** is set for all user instances at once (not for the specific user we want to follow).

I am certainly not following/unfollowing all users at the same time (since the **FollowToggleAPIView** targets a specific user by his username).

I want to know how can I transfer the value of (**is_followed**) only to the specific user (**user_to_toggle**) in the **UserDetailAPIVIew**. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to show the code for the `toggle_follow` method in the UserProfile manager.

Comment: And yes, the value in the session is only updated when you visit FollowToggleAPIView, so it will be the same for any user in UserDetailAPIVIew. Why does that surprise you?

Comment: Dear Daniel thanks for the quick replies. I want the value to be updated for the specific user I want to follow. But it seems this code sets the value for all users (I am following/unfollowing all of them at once).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session is completely the wrong thing to use here. You're storing a single "followed" value which only records the last user they toggled and has no relation to the profile they're actually viewing.

Instead of doing this, you should simply query in the UserDetailAPIVIew the followed status of the specific user.

```
def get_serializer_context(self):
    context = super(UserDetailAPIVIew, self).get_serializer_context()
    is_followed = self.request.user.profile.following.filter(username=self.object).exists()
    context.update({'followed': is_followed})
    return context
```

Note also, your toggle method is itself very inefficient - there's no need to retrieve every follow from the database just to check whether the current user is among them. Use `exists` again:

```
user_profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user) 
if user_profile.following.filter(username=to_toggle_user).exists():
```

Comment: Dear Daniel, I have added the UserProfile() model I am using in my code.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel. With your insights, my code is now working perfectly.